Are LEGO Robotics Clubs/Competitions on-topic?
I'm wondering if questions about LEGO Robotics clubs/organizations such as First LEGO League and associated teams/competitions are on-topic. Questions could conceivably include topics such as teaching/training resources, best practices for organizing teams/competitions, etc. 
